# How to get href value from string

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I'm trying to get the `href` from this string, but I can't because it has space inside the link. I try to do it from regex but I'm not an expert in regex. I tried using an example from the internet but I didn't get the value I was after.

```
<table class="grid border" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_ContentBody_grvStudentResult" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th align="left" valign="middle" scope="col">Code</th>
        <th align="left" valign="middle" scope="col">Subject</th>
        <th align="left" valign="middle" scope="col">Status</th>
        <th align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">Score</th>
        <th align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">Result Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="detail1">
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            DipPM15PQ
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <span class="">
            1561|
            <a onclick="return hs.htmlExpand( this, {  objectType: 'iframe', width: 800, height: 600,  outlineWhileAnimating: true, preserveContent: false } )" href="DetailResults.aspx?sid=90651&amp;id=1769095&amp;nsub= [Project Quality] &amp;Subjectid=1561" title="Approved "> 
            <img alt="" style="display: online" src="../Images/Common/r_Approved.gif" border="0">
            [Project Quality]   </a>
            </span>
            <span class="selected">
            </span>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <span class="enable">
            Competent
            </span>
            <center style="display: none">
                <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_ContentBody_grvStudentResult_ctl02_chkAP" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentBody$grvStudentResult$ctl02$chkAP" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"><label for="ctl00_ContentBody_grvStudentResult_ctl02_chkAP"> </label></span>
            </center>
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            75.00
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            11/11/2018
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="detail1">
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            DipPM15PC
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <span class="">
            1559|
            <a onclick="return hs.htmlExpand( this, {  objectType: 'iframe', width: 800, height: 600,  outlineWhileAnimating: true, preserveContent: false } )" href="DetailResults.aspx?sid=90898&amp;id=1769088&amp;nsub= [Project Costs] &amp;Subjectid=1559" title="NAN "> 
            <img alt="" style="display: online" src="../Images/Common/r_.gif" border="0">
            [Project Costs]   </a>
            </span>
            <span class="selected">
            [progress]
            </span>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <span class="disable">
            </span>
            <center style="display: none">
            </center>
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to parse HTML is to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). You can use it to process your HTML and find the `hrefs` from all the `<a>` tags in your HTML. I'm assuming your HTML is in a variable called `$html`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $urls[] = $a->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue . "\n";
}
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo $url;
}
```

Output

```
DetailResults.aspx?sid=90651&id=1769095&nsub= [Project Quality] &Subjectid=1561 
DetailResults.aspx?sid=90898&id=1769088&nsub= [Project Costs] &Subjectid=1559
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AopOr)

If you **have** to use regex, this will work for your sample data:

```
preg_match_all('/href="([^"]+)/', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => DetailResults.aspx?sid=90651&amp;id=1769095&amp;nsub= [Project Quality] &amp;Subjectid=1561
    [1] => DetailResults.aspx?sid=90898&amp;id=1769088&amp;nsub= [Project Costs] &amp;Subjectid=1559 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aHt0o)

Comment: Hi Brow, thanks for help me ! :)
So i check your demo link and it's really work...
But for this project, i really need to do by regex =/

Comment: @GustavoFilgueiras regex really isn't a good way to parse HTML. But if you have to, I've added a possible solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert but this work for me

```
$string ='<a onclick="return hs.htmlExpand( this, {  objectType: \'iframe\', width: 800, height: 600,  outlineWhileAnimating: true, preserveContent: false } )" href="DetailResults.aspx?sid=90651&amp;id=1769095&amp;nsub= [Project Quality] &amp;Subjectid=1561" title="Approved "> 
            <img alt="" style="display: online" src="../Images/Common/r_Approved.gif" border="0">
            [Project Quality]   </a>';
preg_match_all( '~<a .*?href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>~', $string, $match );

$urls=array();//array of link
foreach($match as $m){
 if (isset($m[0])) {
    $url[]= $m[0];
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for help me brow!
But it's dosen't work well =/

Comment: @GustavoFilgueiras Can you elaborate on exactly what doesn't work well, and how you'd like it to work better?

Comment: this regex used on WordPress to get all image from a post.you can use this to get any attribute.

Comment: Yes, sorry! So i need all the links insde the array, like

Comment: $url = []
$url = "DetailResults.aspx?sid=90651&amp;id=1769095&amp;nsub= [Project Quality] &amp;Subjectid=1561"
$url = "DetailResults.aspx?sid=90898&amp;id=1769088&amp;nsub= [Project Costs] &amp;Subjectid=1559"